# JMeter remote testing, test results not being displayed

Tags: linux, jmeter, remoteobject

I am currently running a remote test plan through a Linux machine.  On the Linux machine, I run `./jmeter-server`, and on host I use the GUI to `Remote Start > IP Address`.  The Linux machine indicates start and completion of test plan through command line, but no results are results are displayed on the GUI.

I know the test plan is working for sure because I have checked memory usage in the Linux machine.  I'm not sure if this is relevant but when I check jmeter.log in the Linux machine, I'm seeing this error:

```
FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:433)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:192)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:232)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:218)
```

What is wrong that I can't see the result data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There could be any number of things wrong. Without more detail it will be very hard for anyone on SO to help you.

Comment: I have updated the post with a little more information.  Wht other type of information could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to jmeter-server java options:

```
 -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

what ls the version of java you are using ?

Comment: I'm currently using Java 1.6 on both machines

Answer (score 0):

After more troubleshooting, I solved the issue.  I had multiple network connections and it seems the response was getting lost in another network which and not reaching the master JMeter GUI which caused no response.  See http://ksdntechnicaldiary.blogspot.ca/ for more information.